# Thread synchronisation issue C++

Tags: multithreading

Have 2 threads, T1 is getting stuck executing a call. 
And at the same time another thread T2 gets disconnected.

During T2's disconnection it performs clean up of T1 and then itself.
Since T1 is blocked. T2 is also not responding and its causing other unwanted behavior of the software.

One possible soln is to have a wait limit on T1. Is this the best way to handle?

Comment: If you want c++ solution you should provide MCVE, if you ask general question about multi processing you should drop c++ tag.

Comment: Thanks sure will drop the c++ tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution is to introduce a third thread:

T3 creates T1 and T2. T1 is executing a call and is blocked. T2 is finished, but does not need to wait for T1, because the clean up is the responsibility of T3. There is no unwanted behaviour of T2 being blocked.